# How to use Mockito to mock including an EntityManager

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Currently in school we are working on a rather large project. However testing in Java wasn't really explained that well so I didn't really work TDD like I was suppose to.

```
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return EntityController.getEntityManager();
}

// Get all exam skeletons from the DB
@Override
public List<ExamSkeleton> getAllSkeletons() {
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
    try {
        TypedQuery<ExamSkeleton> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT NEW ExamSkeleton (s.id, s.filename, s.course, s.visible) FROM ExamSkeleton as s", ExamSkeleton.class);

        List<ExamSkeleton> skeletons = query.getResultList();

        return skeletons;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        LOGGER.error(exception);
    }
        return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

So my question is, how do I test this method using Mockito?

Comment: Note that updating the question according to the answer(s) is not necessarily nice even if it comes from a good feeling. It may indeed make the answers less understandable.

Comment: Currently updated the question because I have an extra problem after this is solved I am planning on changing the question back to its original state.

Comment: Great for the undo :) Good programming !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Approach 1: Test the Code *As Is*

The `getEntityManager` method is private and it invokes a static method so, as things stand, you would need to use PowerMockito to provide a mocked instance of `EntityManager` in your test. For example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({EntityController.class})
public class SomeTest {

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(EntityController.class);

        EntityManager entityManager = Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class);
        Mockito.when(EntityController.getEntityManager()).thenReturn(entityManager);

        TypedQuery<ExamSkeleton> query = (TypedQuery<ExamSkeleton>) Mockito.mock(TypedQuery.class);

        Mockito.when(entityManager.createQuery("SELECT NEW ExamSkeleton (s.id, s.filename, s.course, s.visible) FROM ExamSkeleton as s")).thenReturn(query);

        List<ExamSkeleton> expected = new ArrayList<>();
        Mockito.when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(expected);

        ExamRepository examRepository = new ExamRepository();

        List<ExamSkeletons> actual = examRepository.getAllSkeletons();

        // this assertion verifies that getAllSkeletons gives you the result of the above SQl query
        assertSame(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

### Approach 2: Refactor For Separation of Concerns and Ease of Testing

However, you could simplify things, from a testing and design perspective, by externalising the creation of the entity manager into a factory, for example.

```
public class EntityManagerFactory {

    public EntityManager create() {
        return EntityController.getEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Next, inject an instance of `EntityManagerFactory` into whatever class contains `getAllSkeletons()` (i.e. the class you are testing). The simplest way of doing this is to declare it as a constructor argument:

```
public class SomeDao {
    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public SomeDao(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ExamSkeleton> getAllSkeletons() {
        try {
            TypedQuery<ExamSkeleton> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT NEW ExamSkeleton (s.id, s.filename, s.course, s.visible) FROM ExamSkeleton as s", ExamSkeleton.class);

            List<ExamSkeleton> skeletons = query.getResultList();

            return skeletons;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
            LOGGER.error(exception);
        }
            return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Now, you can test this code using vanilla mockito. For example:

```
public class SomeDaoTest {

    @Test
    public void canGetAllSkeletons() {
       EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Mockito.mock(EntityManagerFactory.class);

       Mockito.when(entityManagerFactory.create()).thenReturn(entityManager);

       SomeDao sut = new SomeDao(entityManagerFactory.class);

       // now SomeDao will use your mocked EntityManager so you can set expectations
       // on createQuery etc to drive your test scenarios
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow ok, so this is alot of new information all at once. If I break it down (I do want the best/cleanest code) I actually have an EntityController class that also has a Factory. I will add this code to the question if that changes anything.

Comment: There are two separate approaches in this answer I have reformatted the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so say I want to use option 1 and keep my dirty code. I am even unsure how to use it. I don't know what goes in the part where you have comments. This is my first time coming into contact with Mockito

Comment: I have updated the answer to show a complete test for the happy path, you'll need to add a separate test to cover the case where the entity manager throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks again for the addition, if I use examSkeleton for instance in the TypedQuery do I have to mock my examSkeleton like this (changed my original upload) the way it is now still getting an error.

Comment: Apologies, I can't understand your last comment. However, based on the implementation of `getAllSkeletons()` shown in your quesiton I cannot think of any reason why you would need to mock `ExamSkeleton`.

Comment: The way my code is right now, I get the error message that I wrote above the second to last lign. I removed the @mock annotations like you mentioned

Comment: This won't compile `ExamRepository.getAllSkeletons();` because `getAllSkeletons` is not a static method i.e. the method definition does not include the word "static". Instead, just create an _instance_ of the repository class e.g. `ExamRepository examRepository = new ExamRepository(); List<ExamSkeletons> actual = examRepository.getAllSkeletons();`

Comment: Wow naturally, rookie mistake after changing this however now I am getting a nullpointer exception..

Comment: It feels like this question might be getting out of control. I'll give it one last try ... I can't diagnose the NullPointerException without having any details about where it occurs so perhaps you could update your question to show 1. the ExamRepository class; 2. the ExamRepositoryTest class and 3. a stack trace for the NullPointerException.

Comment: I feel the same way, I am allready going to accept this answer as the correct one seeing as you did infact very nicely solve the problem. Will update with the requested things in 1 moment.

Comment: @glytching  I am sorry but `PowerMock` and `Mockito` for a method with almost no logic , it is really overkill.

Comment: @davidxx agreed, I certainly wouldn't choose to do that. The answer provides two alternatives and (I think) hints at the second being preferable to the first.

Comment: @glytching I am going to try the second method for sure, however I have a pressing deadline that just needs to pass the tests. After this deadline I am planning changing a whole bunch about the code for which I don't have the time atm.

Comment: The stacktrace suggests that `EntityController.getEntityManager()` returns null. I have created some scratch versions of your classes and I cannot reproduce that so there must be something about your setup (perhaps something in the EntityController class or the versions of Power/Mockito you are using) which is causing `EntityController.getEntityManager()` to return null despite the use of PowerMockito. We'd need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to diagnose that.

Comment: Note: the second approach really is the more correct one and flipping to that could be as as simple as declaring a constructor on `ExamRepository` which accepts an `EntityManager` and then just passing in your mocked `EntityManager` when you construct the `ExamRepository` in `ExamRepositoryMockitoTest`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will do a couple all-nighters and change a few things about how my code works! Diserve all the rep in the world!

Answer (score 0):

1) The EntityManager should not be associated to the controller :

```
return EntityController.getEntityManager();
```

In terms of design, it is not desirable : low layer and high layer should not be mixed, otherwise why use them ?
In terms of testing for `getAllSkeletons()`, this coupling will also make the unit test harder to set and to write.

2) The actual method doesn't have logic to test but the exception case : you just create a query, execute it and return the result.
It is a good case for an integration test (without mocking the DB layer), less for an unit test.
As it will make the unit test complex and with not a lot of value.

---

Example of what you could get with Mockito and that I don't recommend.
Make the `EntityManager` a dependency of the class under test : with injection or not.
In your unit test, mock this dependency.
It could look like :

```
@Mock
EntityManager entityManagerMock;

@Test
public void getAllSkeletons(){
   TypedQuery<ExamSkeleton> queryByMock =  (TypedQuery<ExamSkeleton>)   Mockito.mock(TypedQuery.class);
   Mockito.when(entityManagerMock.createQuery("SELECT NEW ExamSkeleton (s.id, s.filename, s.course, s.visible) FROM ExamSkeleton as s"))
          .thenReturn(queryByMock);
   List<ExamSkeleton> skeletons = new ArrayList<>();
   Mockito.when(queryByMock.getResultList())
          .thenReturn(skeletons);
   Foo foo = new Foo(); 
   foo.setEntityManager(entityManagerMock);
   // action
   List<ExamSkeleton> actualSkeletons = foo.getAllSkeletons();
   // assertion
   Assert.assertSame(skeletons, actualSkeletons);        
}
```

**Really don't write this kind of code that just describes the flow of invocations.**
It makes just a test brittle that will very rarely catch regressions.

Comment: Well first off thanks for the fast reply, second of all I realise this is bad code because I couldn't make a test for it. If we learned how to write code using TDD I would have noticed sooner. The issue I currently have is this is the kind of code I have and my deadline is this monday. My teacher for some reason wants 100% test coverage (checked using sonarcube) meaning I have to test it. Will the code you created below fullfill those demands? I realise using this is bad coding

Comment: You are very welcome. The example code will cover indeed the code of the method. You should of course add a test for the case with the exception where the result is different.